# Plural em time_ago

Tags: php

Estou tendo problema em determina o plural na exibição do tempo.

Função:

```js
/**
 * @ http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#71342
 */
function time_ago($timestamp, $recursive = 0)
{
 $current_time = time();
 $difference = $current_time - $timestamp;
 $periods = array("segundo", "minuto", "hora", "dia", "semana", "mês", "ano", "década");
 $lengths = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);
 for ($val = sizeof($lengths) - 1; ($val >= 0) && (($number = $difference / $lengths[$val]) <= 1); $val--);
 if ($val < 0) $val = 0;
 $new_time = $current_time - ($difference % $lengths[$val]);
 $number = floor($number);
 if($number != 1)
 {
  $periods[$val] .= "s";
 }
 $text = sprintf("%d %s ", $number, $periods[$val]);   
 
 if (($recursive == 1) && ($val >= 1) && (($current_time - $new_time) > 0))
 {
  $text .= time_ago($new_time);
 }
 return $text;
}
```

```html
<span class="time"><?=time_ago($item['mtime'])?> atrás</span>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma solução simples seria apenas remover o "s" do `$periods[$val] .= "s";`, só que ficaria algo meia boca como "5 mês atrás", o certo é deixar "5 meses atrás".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só adicionar mais algumas condições, verifique também o valor de `$val`, ele for 5 então adiciona "eses" se não, adiciona "ês", observe que no plural mês não tem ascento, no array deixei apenas o "m", e depois adicionei o restante através dos if

```
<?php
function time_ago($timestamp, $recursive = 0)
{
    $current_time = time();
    $difference = $current_time - $timestamp;
    $periods = array("segundo", "minuto", "hora", "dia", "semana", "m", "ano", "década");
    $lengths = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);
    for ($val = sizeof($lengths) - 1; ($val >= 0) && (($number = $difference / $lengths[$val]) <= 1); $val--);
    if ($val < 0) $val = 0;
    $new_time = $current_time - ($difference % $lengths[$val]);
    $number = floor($number);
    if($number == 1 && $val == 5)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "ês";
    }
    else if($number != 1 && $val == 5)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "eses";
    }
    else if($number != 1)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "s";
    }
    $text = sprintf("%d %s ", $number, $periods[$val]);   

    if (($recursive == 1) && ($val >= 1) && (($current_time - $new_time) > 0))
    {
        $text .= time_ago($new_time);
    }
    return $text;
}
?>

<span class="time"><?=time_ago(time() -  (40 * 24 * 60 * 60))?> atrás</span> <! Mostra 1 mês atrás >
<span class="time"><?=time_ago(time() -  (70 * 24 * 60 * 60))?> atrás</span> <! Mostra 2 meses atrás >
```

Comment: Conseguiu solucionar um, porem aparece outro kkkk https://i.imgur.com/5SSVWZx.png

Comment: já estou quase desistindo, já procurei em todo o google e não acho solução alguma.

Comment: editei a resposta veja se resolveu

Comment: acabei de testa, funcionou perfeitamente. muito obrigado, passei o dia todo quebrando cabeça com isso :)

Answer (score 0):

Vi que já resolveu, porém em minha opinião eu iria preferir utilizar a ternária, pois o único caso em que não é necessário a concatenação com a letra "s", é especificamente na palavra mês e apenas esta, logo vou deixar a resposta aqui:

```
    /**
     *  @ http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#71342
     */
    function time_ago($timestamp, $recursive = 0)
    {
        $current_time = time();
        $difference = $current_time - $timestamp;
        $periods = array("segundo", "minuto", "hora", "dia", "semana", "mês", "ano", "década");
        $lengths = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);
        for ($val = sizeof($lengths) - 1; ($val >= 0) && (($number = $difference / $lengths[$val]) <= 1); $val--);
        if ($val < 0) $val = 0;
        $new_time = $current_time - ($difference % $lengths[$val]);
        $number = floor($number);
        if($number != 1)
        {
            $periods[$val] = ($periods[$val] === 'mês' ? "meses" : $periods[$val] . "s");
        }
        $text = sprintf("%d %s ", $number, $periods[$val]);   

        if (($recursive == 1) && ($val >= 1) && (($current_time - $new_time) > 0))
        {
            $text .= time_ago($new_time);
        }
        return $text;
    }

    $teste = time_ago(1519862400);
    print($teste);
```

Comment: realmente funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado por compartilhar.