# Duplicação de valor em listagem de diretório PHP

Tags: php

A função desse código e lista arquivos em um diretório, no entanto esta com um erro misterioso.

O problema e o seguinte, quando tem apenas um arquivo dentro da pasta, ele mostra o arquivo e mostra uma pasta com o mesmo nome, ou quando tem mais de um arquivo, ele mostra apenas um único arquivo e mostra uma pasta com o mesmo nome.

Quando tem apenas um arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tem mais de um arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<?php

error_reporting(1);

/***[ CONFIGURAÇÕES ]***/ 

// Definir propriedades de classificação.
$sort = array(
 array('key'=>'lname', 'sort'=>'asc'), // ... isso define a classificação inicial "coluna" e ordem ...
 array('key'=>'size', 'sort'=>'asc') // ... para itens com o mesmo valor de classificação inicial, classifique dessa maneira.
);
// Os arquivos que você deseja ocultar formam a listagem
$ignore_list = array('');

/***[ LÓGICA DE DIRETÓRIO ]***/
// Obter esta pasta e nome de arquivos.

$this_script = basename(__FILE__);
$this_folder = str_replace('/'.$this_script, '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$this_domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$dir_name = explode("/", $this_folder);
//$dir_name = explode("/",dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
//$dir_path = explode("/", $this_folder);


 
// Declare vars usados ​​além deste ponto.

$file_list = array();
$folder_list = array();
$total_size = 0;

$filetype = array(
 'doc' => array('doc','docs','docx','pptx','pdf','pages','key','numbers','xls','ppt','odt','ods','odp','odg','odc','odi','xml','x-office-document'),
 'text'  => array('txt', 'rtf', 'text', 'nfo', 'md', 'markdown'),
 'iso' => array('iso'),
 'audio'  => array('aac', 'mp3', 'wav', 'wma', 'm4p','spx', 'ogg', 'oga', 'midi', 'mid'),
 'image' => array('ai', 'bmp', 'eps', 'gif', 'ico', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'psd', 'psp', 'raw', 'tga', 'tif', 'tiff','icns'),
 'video'  => array('mv4', 'bup', 'mkv', 'ifo', 'flv', 'vob', '3g2', 'bik', 'xvid', 'divx', 'wmv', 'avi', '3gp', 'mp4', 'mov', '3gpp', '3gp2', 'swf', 'mpg', 'ogv','x-shockwave-flash','mpeg'),
 'archive' => array('7z', 'dmg', 'rar', 'sit', 'zip', 'bzip', 'gz', 'tar','pkg','safariextz','bz2','bz','deb', 'x-compressed-tar'),
 'app'  => array('ipa', 'exe', 'msi', 'mse', 'app'),
 'script' => array('js', 'html', 'htm', 'xhtml', 'jsp', 'asp', 'aspx', 'php', 'xml', 'css', 'plist', 'sh', 'bat'),
 'torrent'  => array('torrent')
);

// Abra o diretório atual...
if ($handle = opendir('.'))
{
 // ...comece a digitalizar através dele.
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
 {
  // Certifique-se de que não listamos esta pasta, arquivo ou seus links.
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != $this_script && !in_array($file, $ignore_list))
  {
   // Obter informações sobre o arquivo
   $stat    = stat($file); // ... lento, mas mais rápido que usando filemtime () & filesize ().
   $info    = pathinfo($file);
   // Organize as informações do arquivo.
   $item['name']  = $info['filename'];
   $item['lname']  = strtolower($info['filename']);
   $item['ext']  = $info['extension'];
   $item['lext']  = strtolower($info['extension']);
   if($info['extension'] == '') $item['ext'] = '.';
   
   if(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['doc'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-document';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['text'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-text';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['iso'])){
   $item['class'] = 'type-iso';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['audio'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-audio';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['image'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-image';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['video'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-video';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['archive'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-archive';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['app'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-app';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['script'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-script';
   }elseif(in_array($item[lext], $filetype['torrent'])){
    $item['class'] = 'type-torrent';
   }else{
    $item['class'] = 'type-generic';   
   }
   $item['bytes'] = $stat['size'];
   $item['size'] = bytes_to_string($stat['size'], 2);
   $item['mtime'] = $stat['mtime'];

   // Add files to the file list...
   if($info['extension'] != ''){
    array_push($file_list, $item);
   }

   // ...and folders to the folder list.
   else{
    array_push($folder_list, $item);
   }
   // Limpar cache stat () para liberar memória (não é realmente necessário).

   clearstatcache();

   // Adicione este tamanho de arquivo de itens ao tamanho total desta pasta
   $total_size += $item['bytes'];
        }
    }
 // Feche o diretório quando terminar.
    closedir($handle);
}
// Ordenar lista de pastas.
if($folder_list)
 $folder_list = php_multisort($folder_list, $sort);
// Ordenar lista de arquivos.
if($file_list)
 $file_list = php_multisort($file_list, $sort);
// Calcular o tamanho total da pasta (correção: o tamanho total não pode ser exibido enquanto não houver pasta dentro do diretório)
if($file_list && $folder_list || $file_list)
 $total_size = bytes_to_string($total_size, 2);

$total_folders = count($folder_list);
$total_files = count($file_list);


if ($total_folders > 0){
 if ($total_folders > 1){
  $funit = 'pastas';
 }else{
  $funit = 'pasta';
 }
 $contained = $total_folders.' '.$funit;
}
if ($total_files > 0){
 if($total_files > 1){
  $iunit = 'itens';
 }else{
  $iunit = 'item';
 }
 if (isset($contained)){
  $contained .= ' &amp; '.$total_files.' '.$iunit;
 }else{
  $contained = $total_files.' '.$iunit; 
 }
}

/**
 * http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#83117
 */
 
function php_multisort($data,$keys)
{
 foreach ($data as $key => $row)
 {
  foreach ($keys as $k)
  {
   $cols[$k['key']][$key] = $row[$k['key']];
  }
 }
 $idkeys = array_keys($data);
 $i=0;
 foreach ($keys as $k)
 {
  if($i>0){$sort.=',';}
  $sort.='$cols['.$k['key'].']';
  if($k['sort']){$sort.=',SORT_'.strtoupper($k['sort']);}
  if($k['type']){$sort.=',SORT_'.strtoupper($k['type']);}
  $i++;
 }
 $sort .= ',$idkeys';
 $sort = 'array_multisort('.$sort.');';
 eval($sort);
 foreach($idkeys as $idkey)
 {
  $result[$idkey]=$data[$idkey];
 }
 return $result;
} 

/* START / INICIO [ SIZE / TAMANHO ]
@ http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#84652 */

function bytes_to_string($size, $precision = 0) {
 $sizes = array('YB', 'ZB', 'EB', 'PB', 'TB', 'GB', 'MB', 'KB', 'Bytes');
 $total = count($sizes);
 while($total-- && $size > 1024) $size /= 1024;
 $return['num'] = round($size, $precision);
 $return['str'] = $sizes[$total];
 return $return;
}

/* END / FIM [ SIZE / TAMANHO ] */

/* START / INICIO [ TIME / TEMPO ]
@ http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#71342
@ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295389/plural-em-time-ago */

function time_ago($timestamp, $recursive = 0)
{
 $current_time = time();
 $difference = $current_time - $timestamp;
 $periods = array("segundo", "minuto", "hora", "dia", "semana", "m", "ano", "década");
    $lengths = array(1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560, 315705600);
    for ($val = sizeof($lengths) - 1; ($val >= 0) && (($number = $difference / $lengths[$val]) <= 1); $val--);
    if ($val < 0) $val = 0;
    $new_time = $current_time - ($difference % $lengths[$val]);
    $number = floor($number);
    if($number == 1 && $val == 5)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "ês";
    }
    else if($number != 1 && $val == 5)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "eses";
    }
    else if($number != 1)
    {
        $periods[$val] .= "s";
    }
    $text = sprintf("%d %s atrás", $number, $periods[$val]);   

    if (($recursive == 1) && ($val >= 1) && (($current_time - $new_time) > 0))
    {
        $text .= time_ago($new_time);
    }
    return $text;
}

/* END / FIM [ TIME / TEMPO ] */

/* START / INICIO [ TRANSLATION / TRADUÇÃO ]
@ Send translations to <theingeniouswiz@newroots.de> */

$translation["english"] = array(
 "name_mod" => "file name",
 "size_mod" => "size",
 "date_mod" => "file date",
 "create_dir" => "Create Directory",
 "upload_dir" => "Upload"
);

$translation["portugues"] = array(
 "name_mod" => "nome dos arquivos",
 "size_mod" => "tamanho",
 "date_mod" => "data de modificação",
 "create_dir" => "Criar pasta",
 "upload_dir" => "Upload"
);

// DEFINIR TRADUÇÃO PADRÃO.
$language = "portugues";

if (!isset($translation[$language]))
 $language = "english";
$_ = $translation[$language];

/* END / FIM [ TRANSLATION / TRADUÇÃO ] */


?>


<!--[ TEMPLATE HTML ]-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
   <title>Dashboard</title>
   <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
     <img src="img/logo.png">
     <h3>
      <a href=".." onclick="return confirm('Você tem certeza que deseja voltar?')">Página Inicial</a> / <a href=".">Default</a>
     </h3>
    </header>   
    <ul id="list">
     <li class="header">
      <span class="name"><?=sprintf($_['name_mod']);?></span>
      <span class="size"><?=sprintf($_['size_mod']);?></span>
      <span class="time"><?=sprintf($_['date_mod']);?></span>
      
     </li>
   <!-- PASTAS -->
    <? if($folder_list): ?>
     <? foreach($folder_list as $item) : ?>
      <li class="folder">
       <span class="name">
        <a href="<?=$item['name']?>/"><?=$item['name']?></a>
       </span>
       <span class="size">-</span>
      </li>
     <? endforeach; ?>
    <? endif; ?>
   <!-- /PASTAS -->
   <!-- ARQUIVOS -->
    <? if($file_list): ?>
     <? foreach($file_list as $item) : ?>
       <li class="file <?=$item['class']?>">
        <span class="name">
         <a href="<?=$item['name']?>.<?=$item['ext']?>"><?=$item['name']?>.<?=$item['ext']?></a>
        </span>
        <span class="size"><?=$item['size']['num']?>
         <em><?=$item['size']['str']?></em>
        </span>
        <span class="time"><?=time_ago($item['mtime'])?></span>

       </li>
     <? endforeach; ?>
    <? endif; ?>
   <!-- /ARQUIVOS -->
    <? if($file_list): ?>
     <li class="footer"><?=$contained?>, <?=$total_size['num']?> <?=$total_size['str']?> de tamanho</li>
    <? endif; ?>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código é cheio de redundâncias, mas vou focar no problema:

```
            // Adicione arquivos à lista de arquivos ...
// AQUI:
// Você adiciona o ítem nos arquivos:

            if($info['extension'] != ''){
                array_push($file_list, $item);
            }
            $item['bytes']      =   $stat['size'];
            $item['size']       =   bytes_to_string($stat['size'], 2);
            $item['mtime']      =   $stat['mtime'];
            // Adicione arquivos à lista de arquivos ...
// LOGO EM SEGUIDA
// Você adiciona novamente, desta vez
// com um ELSE (mas a adição anterior já foi feita!)

            if($info['extension'] != ''){
                array_push($file_list, $item);
            }
            // ...e pastas para a lista de pastas.
            else{
                array_push($folder_list, $item);
            }
```

Comment: não entendi, eu deveria remover o else?

Comment: @VitorHugo o problema é que você dá array_push duas vezes no mesmo item, como vai resolver aí depende da intenção do código. O que não pode é adicionar duas vezes e querer que apareça uma só. A parte do else não é a que dá problema.

Comment: eu corrigi o código como você mencionou, porem ainda esta com o mesmo erro

Comment: acabei de editar a pergunta com a sua correção, vou dar a pergunta como resolvida, pois infelizmente o pessoal em vez de ajudar aqui fica negativando a pergunta dos outros, obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim.